# Why is 逮捕 repeated twice?

Tags: parsing, newspaper-grammar

Why 逮捕 is repeated twice in the following newsflash from テレ朝?

> 行方不明の女子高校生の遺体発見　逮捕された20代女の夫も死体遺棄容疑で逮捕

Would the meaning of the sentence change if 逮捕された is omitted?

> 20代女の夫も死体遺棄容疑逮捕

Comment: What is your understanding of the sentence? Who does 逮捕された refer to? There are two people mentioned after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first "逮捕された" is referred to 20代女, so:

- **逮捕**された+20代女 | の | 夫も | 死体遺棄容疑(で)**逮捕**
- *The husband of the **arrested** woman in her 20s was also **arrested** for dumping the body.*

Notice the ***arrested*** is used twice.

Hence the first "逮捕された" is needed, but if it had been stated earlier that the woman had been arrested, I think you can omit that. Though, if I were to write the newsflash, I would not omit it: Because it'd be easier to understand the sentence with it.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the flow. The husband was arrested on suspicion of disposing the body. What is still unclear - on what suspicion the woman was arrested. Sorry, I omitted the first part of the newsflash. I updated my question. Originally I thought that the woman in her 20s was dead and her husband was arrested for killing her and disposing her body, but now I understand that a high school girl cannot be in her 20s :)

Comment: @user1602 As far as I can tell from that news flash, she's accused of abandonment of corpse. Since there's "も" which suggests that the woman is an accomplice. Well, in this case, the husband is accomplice, the principal is woman, though - Since woman got arrested first. It's just a guess though. I believe they both will be accused murder and abandonment of corpse in court, but not right now; Because at this moment, the police doesn't have an evidence and/or confession of murder.

Comment: If the woman was accused of abandonment, shouldn't the order be the following? 死体遺棄容疑で逮捕された20代女の夫も逮捕

Comment: @user1602 In this case, the husband *also* got accused of abandonment of corpse. Since the woman was already arrested by police, the main target of this newsflash is her husband; Thus, this newsflash is more focused on the husband's crime(abandonment of corpse), not the womans. That's why the order is like that.